# C# Parallel.For

Tags: c#, parallel.for

Is the anyway to increase the number of loops a Parallel.For will do once it has started? Example below:

```
var start = 0;
var end = 5;
Parallel.For(start, end, i =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    end = 10;
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Jay

Comment: Number of loops?  There's only one loop.  Do you mean number of iterations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the `end` variable (listed as `toExclusive` [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299.aspx)) is not available within the scope of the lambda.